# how to make the borders of a window wider in gnome 3.26?

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-3

I am running gnome 3.26 under Fedora 27, but this question has actually bugged me for a while.
How do I make the borders on a window wider?  I try to resize the windows by dragging the borders right and left, up and down, and that works.  But it is hard to get my mouse at precisely the right place.  If the border was even 5 pixels wide (10 would be better for me), then that would be much easier.

I tried finding the setting using gconftool-2 but I couldn't find anything in there at all, let alone anything useful.

I realize that this is a small thing.  Considering how often I resize a window, it becomes a bigger deal.  I've done a lot of google searches and have not found anything useful.  I cannot believe that I am the first person to mention gnome window border width , am I?

Thank you

Comment: Are you aware that you can resize windows to fullscreen/half-screen by pressing Super (usually Windows) key + up/left/right/down? You can also resize to any size by pressing Alt+F8 and moving the mouse.

Comment: I did not know that, thank you.  That helps.n  But I'd still like to know how to make the borders wider.  Everything else in gnome seems to be customizable.

Comment: Borders are important for SEEING the window .. borders.I'm having issues with stacked windows with the same background colour.

Answer (score 2):

Type the following in your Terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter draggable-border-width 15
```

**10 is the default value**, but I guess you'll be happy with a more sloppy mouse dragging border.  Adjust to your personal taste.

Have a ball!